# Is there a way to determine when voice text input occurs in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, siri

None of the UITextFieldDelegate methods get fired when using voice input on the iPhone 4S.  I also tried using the UIControl event valueChanged, but that doesn't fire.  Finally, I attempted KVO on the text property of the text field, and that doesn't fire either.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Just to check - you didn't forget to set up the delegate did you?

Comment: Nope, because it fires for normal text events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to suggest this, but seeing as how the usual methods has been tried without success, how about a `NSTimer` that polls the textfield?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Certainly not optimal, but it will work until the delegate handles this properly.